# How to insert sessions in the report designer of the MS Business Intelligence Studio for the MS Reporting Service?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, business-intelligence

I'm trying to migrate our reporting from Crystal report to MS Reporting Service. In the Crystal Report report designer, I can organize sections of the report, including inserting sections, adding suppress conditions. Please kindly advise how can I achieve those in MS Business Intelligence Studio (built in Visual Studio 2008).

Thank you!

BRs,
William Choi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To organize sections, take a look at Subreports. You can add several elements to a subreport, and then add the subreport to the main report. Then you can set the visibility of the whole subreport in an expression.

[MSDN: SSRS Subreports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Uggghh. Avoid subreports wherever possible - try looking at eg. inserting groups and formatting group headers/footers in table objects, instead.

Comment: From the sound of that groan, I think I misunderstood the idea of what a section is in Crystal reports. If you are working in a table/matrix, then the suggestion of using groups and headers/footers is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

in ssrs you can add new expressions for controlling of the report behaviors. for example you can write an expression for controlling of a textbox visibility.

Comment: Thanks Ramezani, how about adding sections/headers? further, regarding using expression to control the visibility, how can I conditionally switch the rectangle to be displayed in the same region of the report?

Comment: do you want add header and footer dynamically? please give me more info.